# Probability question (2 conditions)

Tags: probability

Female smokers - 20
Male smokers - 40
Total smokers - 60

Non-smoking females - 70
Non-smoking males - 70
Total non-smokers - 140

Total females - 90
Total males - 110
Total - 200

If two people from the survey are selected at random, calculate the probability that
A. both of them are non-smoking females.
B. one is a smoker and the other is a non-smoker.

For A and B, I'm getting near values of the answer.
A: I tried 70/200 * 70/200 to get .125, but the answer is approximately .121

B: I tried multiplying 140/200 * 60/200 + 140/200 * 60/200 to get .42, but the answer is approximately .422

I was just wondering if I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$- The probability is $(70/200)*(69/199)=0.121$ 
$B$- The probability is $(140/200)*(60/199)+(60/200)*(140/199)=0.422$ 
When a person is selected, the other person has to be selected from $200-1=199$ persons. This is the only thing that you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A: the answer should be $$\frac{\dbinom{70}{2}}{\dbinom{200}{2}}=\frac{70}{200} \cdot {\frac{69}{199}}$$.

Your mistake is: when you select $1$ person from $200$, only $199$ (not $200$) people are left.

Same mistake for question B.